# Display data from multiple tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables - USERSS and ZPATECNI. I have the following code, but after this, nothing is displaying. Select is correct - it works in Oracle SQL developer. Id, username and password are from table userss, schvaleno is from zpatecni.

What is wrong?

```
$r = $db->parseAndExecute("SELECT USERSS.ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SCHVALENO"
    . " FROM USERSS JOIN ZPATECNI ON ZPATECNI.ID_OSOBA = USERSS.ID WHERE ADMIN = 'NO'");

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($r, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) != false) {
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['USERNAME'];
    echo $row['PASSWORD'];
    echo $row['SCHVALENO'];
}
```

Comment: are you sure there is a record with `admin` as `no` in your table.Does the record exists in both table. Directly run this SQL in SQL server and see.

Comment: yes, in table userss i have 1 record with admin = no and this select work in  sql developer

Comment: what is `parseAndExecute` ? i see `oci_parse` and `oci_execute`. where did you get this.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: i delete condition where admin = no ... and it works fine, so i leave it and wrote all record... Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 SELECT USERSS.ID,
        USERSS.USERNAME,
        USERSS.PASSWORD,
        USERSS.SCHVALENO 
 FROM USERSS 
 JOIN ZPATECNI ON ZPATECNI.ID_OSOBA = USERSS.ID 
 WHERE ADMIN = 'NO'"
```

Comment: I tryied this, only difference is that I had wrote ZPATECNI.SCHVALENO, because zpatecni is from table zpatecni and it doesnt work..